# Xamarin Forms ActivityIndicator over ListView

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, activity-indicator

My ActivityIndicator is at the bottom of the Page, but it should be in the middle. I tried everything I found in the internet but nothing worked.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxf4e.png)

```
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
      <SearchBar Placeholder="Parkhaus suchen" Text="{Binding SearchText}"/>

      <ListView x:Name="HomeListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Parking}" HasUnevenRows="False"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            ...
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Footer/>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

   <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
   </StackLayout>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Try using grid instead of absolute layout with row1 - listview row2 activity indicator with rowspan=2

Comment: Nothing changes, I have now `<Grid>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"> </StackLayout> <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"> </StackLayout> </Grid>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your StackLayout around your ActivityIndicator to use:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1"
```

The `PositionPropertional` flag tells the AbsoluteLayout that the x and y position of the element is based on the size of the absolute layout, taking the size of the element into account.  So 0.5 tells it to center the element within the AbsoluteLayout.

The values for the width and height are both set to -1.  This is considered a "special value" for width and height meaning "Auto".

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me but it still doesn't work. When I remove the `<ListView>` then the `<ActivityIndicator>` shows up in the middle otherwise it's still at the bottom.

Comment: Now it works I had to but the `<ActivityIndicator>` above the `<ListView>`! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  The `StackLayout` containing the `ListView` must throw off the calculation somehow.  If you surround that `StackLayout` with an `AbsoluteLayout` and move the layout flags from the `StackLayout` into the `AbsoluteLayout` it will also work.